# How to calculate ∆rGº from entropy and ∆fGº in different temperatures?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, entropy, free-energy

"The total oxidation of glucose occurs according to the following chemical equation:

C6H12O6 (s) + 6O2 (g) -> 6CO2 (g) + 6H2O (l)

The following table gives us the free energies of standard formation and the standard molar entropies of
compounds involved in the previous reaction.

| Compound | ∆fGº(298 K) kJ/mol | Smº (298 K) J/K/mol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C6H12O6 | -917,2 | 212,10 |
| O2 | 0 | 205,14 |
| CO2 | -394,36 | 213,14 |
| H20 | -273,13 | 69,91 |

Based on the previous data, determine the ∆rGº
for glucose oxidation at 308 K"

It's a question of a doctoral selection process and I want to figure out if it is formulated wrong or if there is a way to an answer.

Comment: Yes, it is answerable.  From the individual free energies and entropies of formation, you can get delta_G and delta_S for the overall reaction at 298K, from which you can then get delta_H (from delta_G=delta_H – T delta_S).   delta_H in turn gives you the temperature-dependence of the reaction,  from which you can get delta_G at 308K.  Now that you have a roadmap, try working through as much as possible on your own.

Comment: Should not it be rather $\Delta G^{\circ}_f$ and $\Delta G^{\circ}_r$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small temperature change like that, you can make use of dG=-SdT.  Determine $\Delta rG^0$ and $\Delta r S^0$ at 298, multiply the latter by 10 , and subtract it from the former to get $\Delta rG^0$ at 308K.